# React Native Router Flux: How to style NavDrawer's button and navigation bar?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

In React Native Router Flux, I have a functional `react-native-drawer` called `NavDrawer`. It currently has the default hamburger menu icon on the left side of the navigation bar, and would like to change it to another custom icon. So I tried, leftTitle='Menu', yet it didn't change.

**So I was wondering how can I customize the `react-native-drawer`'s default menu icon?**

And I also changed the height of the navigation bar via `navigationBarStyle`, so the buttons currently sit close to the bottom of the navigation bar rather than in the middle. So in the `navigationBarStyle`, I attempted, `flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'`, but did not change anything.

**So how can I center align horizontally the elements in the navigation bar?**

Here is the code:

```
        <Scene key='drawer' component={NavDrawer} open={false}>
          <Scene key="main" navigationBarStyle={styles.navigationBar} onRight={() => Actions.profile()} rightTitle='Profile'>
                        ...
          </Scene>
        <Scene/>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> So I was wondering how can I customize the react-native-drawer's default menu icon?

I use [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) that allows you to choose icons from several different collections, including Google's [Material Icons](https://design.google.com/icons/). Here's what the code looks like in my case:

First, I use the `renderLeftButton` Scene prop to render my custom button.

```
<Scene key='navigationDrawerContentWrapper' navigationBarStyle={SceneStyle.navigationBar} titleStyle={SceneStyle.title}>
   <Scene key='mainScreen' component={MainScreen} title='Main Screen' renderLeftButton={NavigationItems.menuButton} sceneStyle={SceneStyle.scene} initial={true}/>
</Scene>
```

NavigationItems.js looks like this:

```
const menuButton = () => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={openDrawer} style={Dimensions.iconSmall.touchableObject}>
            <Icon name='menu'
                size={24}
                color={#ffffff}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}

const openDrawer = () => {
    Actions.refresh({ key: 'drawer', open: true })
}
```

> So how can I center align horizontally the elements in the navigation bar?

I think you meant align **vertically**. Try [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/325) solution that suggests using a flexbox with the following style:

```
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
```

Comment: Appreciate the response. As for the first example, do you mind showing the full .js of `NavigationItems.js` example you provided for clarification? As for the alignment, yes sorry, I meant vertically center, and I gave it a try as `navigaitonBarStyle`, but the buttons did not move. Is that where I was supposed to style? Thank you again

Comment: Just checking in to see if you saw my previous comment. Please let me know.

Comment: Hello and sorry for the delay. The NavigationItems.js basically contains these two functions. You might as well move them in the same file where you define your scenes. Did you manage to customize the default icon using `react-native-vector-icons` or some other module? As for the alignment, yes, I would expect it to work when setting it as the `navigationBarStyle`. This style should be defined in the parent component of the icons which I guess is the navigation bar.

Comment: Yes I gave the icon a try but did not work. A full example would really help. As for the alignment, I gave it an attempt but the elements did not move at all.